# Gulp - How to change a destination folders permissions?

Tags: gulp

I'm copying a file and creating a new destination folder for that file.

```
return gulp.src('path/to/file/file.jpg')
           .pipe( gulp.dest('path/to/destination');
```

The problem is that the folder that is created has the wrong permissions. I've looked all over and can't seem to find any information on how to change a destination folder's permissions with gulp. I've looked into gulp-chmod, but so far I can only get that to change the permissions of file.jpg within the new folder.

```
gulp.src('path/to/file/file.jpg')
    .pipe(chmod(0o777, true))
    .pipe( gulp.dest('path/to/destination/'));
```

Answer (score 2):

You might try adding a "mode" option to your gulp.dest since you specifically state that you are creating a new folder.  See

[gulp.dest(path[, options])](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/dest#options)

> options.mode
>
> Type: String Default: 0777
> Octal permission string specifying mode for any folders that need to be created for output folder.

So,

```
 .pipe( gulp.dest('path/to/destination', {mode: 0777});
```

although that is the default so I would think you shouldn't need to do it.  I would also try just using 0777 instead of the 0o777 in your chmod call as an easy try.

Comment: Thanks, fixed.  Old link was to gulp v3 docs, now to gulp v4.